# How do I select max date for each row from a subquery

Tags: sql, t-sql

Let's say I want to select the 3 bestsellers in a supermarket. To do this, I have to add each sale to get the total for each product:

```
SELECT TOP(3) *
FROM
(
   SELECT
   SUM(s.individual_sale) AS totalsales,
   p.productID AS ID,
   p.productName AS Name

   FROM
   sales s,
   products p

   WHERE
   1=1
   AND p.productID = s.productID

   GROUP BY
   p.productID,
   p.productName
   ) AS top_sellers

ORDER BY
top_sellers.totalsales DESC
```

It then returns me something like this:

**ID..|.Name.|.totalsales**

55.|.milk....|.1000

24.|.candy.|.800

67.|.juice...|.500

Now I want to retrieve a 4th column containing the last sale from each of these items, like querying "MAX saledate" to each one. How do I accomplish that?

EDIT: Adding MAX(s.saledate) isn't helping. It retrieves a date like 01 Jan 2012 to all rows, but if I query MAX(s.saledate) individually for each entry of the table above, it returns the correct date... My question is, how can I add the column MAX(s.saledate) for each product, using the same query that shows the 3 bestsellers.

Comment: Why doesn't MAX(saledate) work exactly?

Comment: I don't know how to implement it on my code. Could you help me?

Comment: Just like a SUM, except its a MAX... MAX(s.saledate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add `max(s.saledate)` to your query.  The subquery is not needed.  The syntax `t1 join t2 on <predicate>` is considered much more readable than `from t1, t2 where <predicate>`.

```
select  top 3 sum(s.individual_sale) as totalsales
,       p.productID as ID,
,       p.productName as Name
,       max(s.saledate) as MaxSaleDate
from    sales s
join    products p
on      p.productID = s.productID
group by
        p.productID
,       p.productName
order by
        sum(s.individual_sale) desc
```

Comment: Really? Is that it? I haven't tried something this trivial. Gonna give it a shot when I get the chance to access my computer tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: just tried it, and didn't work! it retrieves the same date to all products, when it should be specific to each one (read my edit)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the query will return the latest salesdate **per product**.  If you think it doesn't, see if you can reproduce an example on sqlfiddle.com.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP(3) *
FROM
(
   SELECT
   SUM(s.individual_sale) AS totalsales,
   p.productID AS ID,
   p.productName AS Name, 
   MAX(s.saledate) as MaxSaleDate

   FROM
   sales s,
   products p

   WHERE
   1=1
   AND p.productID = s.productID

   GROUP BY
   p.productID,
   p.productName
   ) AS top_sellers

ORDER BY
top_sellers.totalsales DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

> Add `MAX(saledate)` to your exisitng query.

```
SELECT TOP(3) *
FROM
(
   SELECT
   SUM(s.individual_sale) AS totalsales,
   p.productID AS ID,
   p.productName AS Name,
   MAX(saleDate)

   FROM
   sales s,
   products p

   WHERE
   1=1
   AND p.productID = s.productID

   GROUP BY
   p.productID,
   p.productName
) AS top_sellers

ORDER BY
top_sellers.totalsales DESC
```